# Strcmp() function not working properly

Tags: c++

```
ifstream myfile;//file reading mode
myfile.open("file2.txt");//file opened 

    if(!myfile)
    {
              cout<<"your file cannot be opened";
    }
        for(;!myfile.eof();)
        {
                myfile>>name>>salary>>concerned_department;
                cout<<name<<"\t"<<salary<<"\t"<<concerned_department<<"\n";                 
        }
            do
            {
               cout<<"To search an employee please enter the name of the employee<<"\n";
                cin>>empName;//will take the string from the user.
                cout<<empName<<"\n";
                                    ifstream myfile;//file reading mode
                                    myfile.open("file2.txt");//file opened successfully

                        if(strcmp(name,"empName")==0)//here the main problem lies     
                        {
                            myfile>>name>>salary>>concerned_department;
                            cout<<name<<"\t"<<salary<<"\t"<<concerned_department<<"\n"; 
                        }
                        else
                        {//
                            cout<<"ERROR "could not be compared"<<"\n";
                        }
                            cout<<"Do you want to continue (y/n)";
                            cin>>con;
            }

            while(con=='y');
```

The strcmp() function is not comparing the strings though given. string1 is given in the file whereas the string2 is being taken from the user.

Comment: do you mean to compare `name` to the string literal `"empName"` or to the variable `empName`?  You are doing the former..

Comment: its char name[20] & empName[20];

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we'd be glad to help you out! Could you please provide more explanation to what you've tried and the steps you've taken to try and fix it so we can better help you?

Comment: Please also fix your formatting. Illegible code is, err, illegible.

Comment: have used strcmp() function and tried to compare two arrays, which are name[20] and empName[20] but it is not showing the result which is required

Comment: Take off the quotes around `empName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
if(strcmp(name,empName)==0)
{
     ...
}
```

Note that there must be **no quotation marks** around `empName` to compare its contents.